# Speak Recorded Text When Call Is Received In Android

Tags: android, text-to-speech, telephonymanager, accessibilityservice

I am developing an application in which I want to generate a speech file i.e. written text using text to speech everytime on a Outgoing call. I am able to detect when a receiver answers the call using an Accessibility Service. Here is the code:-

```
public class CallDetection extends AccessibilityService {
@Override
public void onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent event) {

    if (event.getEventType() == AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_WINDOW_CONTENT_CHANGED) {
        Log.i("myaccess", "in window changed");


        AccessibilityNodeInfo info = event.getSource();
        if (info != null && info.getText() != null) {
            String duration = info.getText().toString();
            String zeroSeconds = String.format("%02d:%02d", new Object[]{Integer.valueOf(0), Integer.valueOf(0)});
            String firstSecond = String.format("%02d:%02d", new Object[]{Integer.valueOf(0), Integer.valueOf(1)});
            Log.d("myaccess", "after calculation - " + zeroSeconds + " --- " + firstSecond + " --- " + duration);
            if (zeroSeconds.equals(duration) || firstSecond.equals(duration)) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Call answered", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                // Your Code goes here

            }
            info.recycle();
        }

    }
}

@Override
protected void onServiceConnected() {
    super.onServiceConnected();
    Toast.makeText(this, "Service connected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    AccessibilityServiceInfo info = new AccessibilityServiceInfo();
    info.eventTypes = AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_WINDOW_CONTENT_CHANGED;
    info.feedbackType = AccessibilityServiceInfo.FEEDBACK_GENERIC;
    info.notificationTimeout = 0;
    info.packageNames = null;
    setServiceInfo(info);
}

@Override
public void onInterrupt() {

}
```

}

Now, I am using text to speech to play the voice but that doesn't work here. Neither I am able to use it in the service nor I can here any voice on another phone. I searched and find android doesn't allow an app to send voice during a call. Is that true? Help me in resolving this problem.

Answer (score 3):

What you found is absolutely right. Android API won't allow access to the voice input directly because of security concerns. Therefore **there is no way** to achieve what you are trying to do in normal devices.

Another possibility which comes to our mind is to play an audio clip using during the call.See this quote from [official docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer) about using media player during call

> You can play back the audio data only to the standard output
>   device. Currently, that is the mobile device speaker or a Bluetooth
>   headset. You cannot play sound files in the conversation audio during
>   a call.

The only hop is a **custom OS / hardware** which take the provided audio as the microphone input in normal devices.